# Add Title field after import from Access

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, export, microsoft-access

I was imported some list from ms asscess table and I see that dosn't create Title field and user cant watch list item on click in record. How I can fix that without created simular list and transfer data to them?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your question was lost in translation.

When creating list from import, the first column typically becomes the "title" column allowing users to click on it to edit item. As test try to export your table from MS Access to MS Excel and than use "Import Spreadsheet" option.

Also make sure that you are displaying "fieldname(linked to item with edit menu)" in your view.